# Why my var return incompatibility problem with error 13?

Tags: java, excel, vba

I'm trying to parse Json in VBA.
I'm collecting data from an API that returns a json format in a string.
I use JsonConverter to parse my string.
Now when i want to search on it, i got an error 13 incompatibility type.

See my Java API below :

```
@GetMapping("/rest/collectData/excel/exportAll")
public HashMap<Object, Object> collectAll(){
    HashMap<Object, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    String sql = "SELECT affair_code AS codeAffair, name, amount, end_date AS state FROM service_record WHERE affair_code IS NOT NULL AND affair_code != ''";
    List<Map<String, Object>> allServiceRecords = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);


    if(allServiceRecords != null && allServiceRecords.size() >0){
        result.put("result", true);
        for(Map<String, Object> serviceRecord : allServiceRecords){
            HashMap<Object, Object> details = new HashMap<>();
            if(result.containsKey(serviceRecord.get("codeAffair"))){
                details.put("alone", false);
                details.put("message", "Plusieurs prestations ont été trouvées.");
            } else {
                details.put("alone", true);
                details.put("name", (String) serviceRecord.get("name"));
                details.put("amount", (Double) serviceRecord.get("amount"));
                details.put("state", ((Date) serviceRecord.get("state")).compareTo(new Date()) < 0 ? "En cours" : "Clos");
            }
            result.put(serviceRecord.get("codeAffair"), details);
        }
    } else{
        result.put("result", false);
        result.put("error", "La liste n'est pas définie, ou vide.");
    }

    return result;

}
```

It returns json :

```
{"03-045251":{"alone":true,"amount":0.0,"name":"name1","state":"En cours"},"03_05494":{"alone":true,"amount":16743.0,"name":"name2","state":"En cours"}}
```

First, i execute sql request to collect my data and put it in a map.
Then, i send this map to my excel VBA.

Now see my VBA :

```
Sub JsonDataSqwal()

firstRow = Range("A" & 11).End(xlDown).Row
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim httpObject As Object
Set httpObject = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")


sUrl = "http://localhost/rest/collectData/excel/exportAll"

sRequest = sUrl
httpObject.Open "GET", sRequest, False
httpObject.send
sGetResult = httpObject.responseText

If Not IsNull(sGetResult) Then
    Dim oJson As Object
    JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True
    Set oJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sGetResult)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = firstRow To lastRow
        Dim codeAffString As String
        codeAffString = Cells(i, 4)
        Debug.Print oJson(codeAffString)("name")
    Next i
     
End If
```

End Sub

For the moment, i try to print my data. the loop collects values from a column, which contains all my codeAffair as `00_00000` or `00-00000`

It is this data that i try to use in my vba code with the var `codeAffString`.
When i execute my code, i'm always getting error 13 about type incompatibility.

To solve this, i tried many things :

1. to add quote to my var
2. To rename my HashMap as `HashMap<String, Object>`
3. To allow unquoting keys
4. To change my back office program
5. To replace my value like `"""" + codeAffairString + """"`
6. To replace my var with a fix String `"00_00000"`. It works in this case.
7. To check the type of my var with VarTyp function which returns 8 for String index.

Now i Have no other idea to solve my problem..
If someone see where is my mistake..

Thank you !

Comment: I think the line which cause the problem is `Debug.Print oJson(codeAffString)("name")` caused by the codeAffString type

Comment: I did, sorry :)

Comment: Try to give an [mcve] of the issue that reproduces the problem. As well as which code was used for `JsonConverter` and the exact JSON **string** that you got as a response from your API. That is the only way for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I used the JsonConverter from VBA-tools : https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

Comment: The Json is just an extract, because there are too many elements return from the API. But it is the same structure with more object

Comment: One more question. What is the value of `codeAffString` when the error occurs?

Comment: The value is a Cell  value `03-045251` I tried to set cell type as text or standard it does not change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a quick test:

I used the JSON string you gave and the value you gave for `codeAffString` to build a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and it does not produce any errors:

```
Sub test()
    Const JsonString As String = "{""03-045251"":{""alone"":true,""amount"":0.0,""name"":""name1"",""state"":""En cours""},""03_05494"":{""alone"":true,""amount"":16743.0,""name"":""name2"",""state"":""En cours""}}"
    Const codeAffString As String = "03-045251"
    
    Dim oJson As Object
    JsonConverter.JsonOptions.AllowUnquotedKeys = True
    Set oJson = JsonConverter.ParseJson(JsonString)
    
    Debug.Print oJson(codeAffString)("name")  ' outputs name1
End Sub
```

The error you describe occurs if `codeAffString` cannot be found in the JSON.

Test it by the following in your code:

```
For i = firstRow To lastRow
    Dim codeAffString As String
    codeAffString = Cells(i, 4)
    If IsEmpty(oJson(codeAffString)) Then
        Debug.Print codeAffString & " does not exist in the json"
    Else
        Debug.Print oJson(codeAffString)("name")
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works with your code ! I think the problem was due to some `oJson(codeAffString)` that was empty in the json maybe.